# スクレイピングである要素を新しい要素で挟む方法

Tags: python, python3, beautifulsoup

今現在、beautifulsoup4を使ってスクレイピングを行っています。

やりたいこと
`<div class='ex1'></div>` を`<p id='good'>`で挟む。

```
<p id='good'><div class='ex1'></div></p>
```

HTML

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="1st">最初の章</h1>
           <div class="ex1">
            <ul>
                <li id="foo">項目1</li>
                <li id="bar">項目2</li>
                <li id="bar">項目3</li>
            </ul>
           </div>
           <div class="ex2">
            <ul>
                <li id="foo">項目1</li>
                <li id="bar">項目2</li>
                <li id="bar">項目3</li>
            </ul>
           </div>
    </body> </html>
```

やりたいことのイメージ図

```
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <h1 class="1st">最初の章</h1>
              <p id='good'>
               <div class="ex1">
                <ul>
                    <li id="foo">項目1</li>
                    <li id="bar">項目2</li>
                    <li id="bar">項目3</li>
                </ul>
               </div>
              </p>
               <div class="ex2">
                <ul>
                    <li id="foo">項目1</li>
                    <li id="bar">項目2</li>
                    <li id="bar">項目3</li>
                </ul>
               </div>
        </body> </html>
```

pythonの試したスクリプトと結果

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# htmlは仮でおいています。
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

item = soup.find(class_="ex1")

newtag = soup.new_tag('p',id='good')

item.select('div.item-right')[0].append(newtag)
```

実行結果
div.ex1のタグが閉じるところにアペンドしてしまって、pでdivを挟むことができません。

---

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="1st">最初の章</h1>
           <div class="ex1">
            <ul>
                <li id="foo">項目1</li>
                <li id="bar">項目2</li>
                <li id="bar">項目3</li>
            </ul>
            <p id='good'></p>
            </div>
           <div class="ex2">
            <ul>
                <li id="foo">項目1</li>
                <li id="bar">項目2</li>
                <li id="bar">項目3</li>
            </ul>
           </div>
    </body> </html>
```

Comment: `find()` ではなく、`select_one()` と `wrap()` を使う方法もあります。`soup.select_one('.ex1').wrap(soup.new_tag('p', id='good'))`

Comment: なるほど！wrap()知りませんでした！ありがとうございます。試してみます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# htmlは仮でおいています。
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

soup.select_one(".ex1").wrap(soup.new_tag('p', id='good'))
```

@metropolisさん　引用

上記で解決しました。